# Webpack 5 bundled code not working: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'webpackHotUpdate_<myAppName>' of undefined at jsonp chunk loading:78

Tags: webpack, bundler, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, webpack-5

After updating webpack from 4.46.0 to 5.35.0 as well as plugins, loaders, webpack-dev-server, webpack and webpack-dev-server config, files, I get the following error when running the development server or serving the production build. For development build:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'webpackHotUpdate_<myAppName>' of undefined
at jsonp chunk loading:78
```

Very similar error for production build:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webpackChunk_<myAppName>' of undefined
at jsonp chunk loading:84
```

Would you know what is the cause of this? Thanks.

Comment: add your webpack config file to the post

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the `globalObject: 'this'` setting from `output`.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem, but don't have globalObject set at all. Can you attach your config file by any chance so I can see what other differences might be there?